# Android check a DB exists or not

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

```
private SQLiteDatabase db = null;
private final String DB_NAME = "myDB";
```

I just created a DB and tables. I need to check whether there is a db is present from another button clicking.

```
db = this.openOrCreateDatabase("myDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the database file exist; you can get the database `File` object using [`getDataBasePath()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)):

```
    File dbFile = getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME); // add the database file name like "myDatabase.db"

    if (dbFile.exists())
        Log.d("LOG_TAG", "Database exists");
    else
        Log.d("LOG_TAG", "Database doesn't exists");
```